# How do I access a dictionary definition form another class in C#

Tags: c#, class, dictionary

How can I retrieve the value of the word "Meters" in my Program? I stored the dictionary in the class "Class1" but I don't know how to retrieve it.

This is the class that will call the dictionary.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", Class1.Conversions.Length["Meters"]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This is the class that contains my dictionary.

```
public class Class1
{
    public static Dictionary<string, double> Conversions()
    {
        Dictionary<string, double> Length = new Dictionary<string, double>();

        Length.Add("Meters", 0.3048);
        Length.Add("Feet", 1);

        return Length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", Class1.Conversions()["Meters"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Class + method + the key "Meters" of the dictionary returned by method,

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", Class1.Conversions()["Meters"]);
```